# Alias for function arguments in Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, alias

I have small question. I have function argument writen like

```
f (a,b,c,d,e)
```

Is there any way to refer to whole tuple (a,b,c,d,e) by some alias?

Comment: When you say refer, can you be a little more specific? Maybe with an imaginary code example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like you need [as pattern](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)

```
f o@(a,b,c,d,e) = ...
```